# Archivos bin de Java que se borraron solos y no puedo ejecutar mis programas en eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eso mismo, los archivos bin desaparecieron, los archivos src si están, y no me permite ejecutar mis programas, al ejecutar sale un error en consola de "Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal.". Los archivos bin que no están tampoco los encontre en la papelera.

Comment: Aveces el IDE no detecta la clase principal en la que se quiere hacer "run", en estos casos debes abrir la clase donde se encuentra el método "main" y hacer F11 o presionar el botón de Run. Quizás sea eso.

Comment: Los archivos bin o los que se contienen en el directorio bin?. Revisar [ask],saludos.

Comment: Los archivos que se contienen en el directorio bin. Aún están los que se contienen en el directorio src. ¿Por qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

El problema era el siguiente. Almacene en el directorio bin imágenes, éstas JPG. al eliminarlas de esa carpeta. Aparecieron todos los archivos .class y mi programa comenzó a funcionar devuelta. Si alguien puede comentarme el motivo, lo agradecería.